# Was there a version of "It's a Wonderful Life" or "The Greatest Gift" involving both of them drowning?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, its-a-wonderful-life

For those unfamiliar, *[It's a Wonderful Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Wonderful_Life)* was adapted from "[The Greatest Gift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Greatest_Gift)", both involving a man named George, suicidally despondent and about to jump off of a bridge to cash in on his life insurance policy, (in the film, rescuing an angel named Clarence who falls in the river by jumping in to save him), and granted a vision of what the world would be like without him to make him appreciate his own life.

I have this vague memory of reading that the original story had them, after the vision, drowning, as neither knew how to swim, but of course, when I looked up "The Greatest Gift", that's not the plotline at all, not involving a drowning angel at all. Was there any earlier adaptation of the story that had a bit more of a downer ending?

Comment: Mandela effect??

Comment: @seamusthedog: Probably. :)